# GPU passthrough code 12 in win10 VM on proxmox

Tags: windows-10, pci-express, kvm-switch, nvidia, proxmox

getting code 12 error in device manager.
have tried 538 data center tesla, and 442 tesla desktop drivers.
i cannot open nvidia control center, but on first try i get EULA prompt which i accept and then nothing more.

[device manager+gpu-z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjMhu.png)

**dmesg | grep -e IOMMU**

```
[    0.128824] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.332016] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 0 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 0
[    0.332020] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base  0xfbffc000 IOMMU 0
```

**dmesg | grep remapping**

```
    [    0.332025] DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.
    [    0.332366] DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode

pvesh get /nodes/{nodename}/hardware/pci --pci-class-blacklist ""
    class    │ device │ id           │ iommugroup │ vendor │ device_name
    0x030200 │ 0x1b38 │ 0000:04:00.0 │         27 │ 0x10de │ GP102GL [Tesla P40]
```

**/etc/default/grub**

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on intel_iommu=pt"
```

have tried:

```
    pci=realloc
    initcall_blacklist=sysfb_init
    nomodeset
    vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 pcie_acs_override=downstream video=efifb:off video=vesafb:off
```

**/etc/modules**

```
    vfio
    vfio_iommu_type1
    vfio_pci
    #vfio_virqfd
```

**/etc/modprobe.d/pve-blacklist.conf**

```
    blacklist nvidiafb
    blacklist nouveau
```

**/etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf**

```
    options vfio-pci ids=10de:1b38 disable_vga=1 disable_idle_d3=1
```

have tried:

```
    disable_denylist=1
    pci=realloc
```

**lspci -n -s 04:00 -v**

```
04:00.0 0302: 10de:1b38 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: 10de:11d9
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 24, IOMMU group 27
        Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
        Memory at 3ff000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32G]
        Memory at 3ff800000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32M]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
        Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

**VM .conf:**

```
    agent: 1
    balloon: 0
    bios: ovmf
    boot: order=scsi0;ide0;ide2
    cores: 4
    cpu: x86-64-v2-AES
    efidisk0: ssd-1tb:333/vm-333-disk-0.qcow2,efitype=4m,pre-enrolled-keys=1,size=528K
    hostpci0: 0000:04:00,pcie=1,x-vga=1
    machine: pc-q35-8.1
    memory: 4096
    meta: creation-qemu=8.1.2,ctime=1706034719
    name: passthrough
    net0: e1000=BC:24:11:84:4B:ED,bridge=vmbr0,firewall=1
    numa: 0
    ostype: win10
    scsi0: ssd-1tb:333/vm-333-disk-1.qcow2,iothread=1,size=32G
    scsihw: virtio-scsi-single
    smbios1: uuid=26873cc1-edc2-4493-b09d-82a93e37bb77
    sockets: 1
    tpmstate0: ssd-1tb:333/vm-333-disk-2.raw,size=4M,version=v2.0
    vga: virtio
    vmgenid: 957dfd44-c238-4720-811f-75f72b833405
```

have tried:

```
    args: qm set VMID -args '-global q35-pci host.pci-hole64-size=2048G'
    args: -device vfio-pci,host=1a:00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x10.0 -device vfio-pci,host=1a:00.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x10.1
    args: -cpu host,hv_time,kvm=off,hv_vendor_id=TheNeverhood,-hypervisor -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,id=hostpci0.0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x10.0,multifunction=on -device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,id=hostpci0.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x10.1
```

have also tried setting Display: None, then using remote desktop.

in VM hardware, PCI Device, have tried with and without Primary GPU & ROM-Bar
have tried providing ROM file, original and patched with NVIDIA-vBIOS-VFIO-Patcher